# Determine file type based on data, not extension, using Python

Tags: python

I have many archive files need to be decompress, but these files has random suffix, e.g.:

```
a.gho
b.cuw
c.ghi
```

the real extension of these files maybe is `.zip`, `.rar` or `.7z`.

I would like to determine real file extension So I can decide which module I should use to decompress it, `unrar` or `unzip`.

Is it possible?

For now, the only way I can think of is to try to decompress file one by one. for example, for file a.gho:

```
try unrar g.rar
if not working, try unzip g.zip
```

Obviously, this is inefficient. So, is there a better way to determine real file extension?

Comment: The `file` utility has a database of all kinds of different file types. Does Python have a wrapper around that?

Comment: Have you looked at these files with a hex editor?  It is very easy to tell the difference between those three just by looking at the first 8 bytes.

Comment: @tadman The main one is [`python-magic`](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) (the underlying library is called *libmagic,* humbly.)